# In the Flex SDK, what are the "extra" .swc files in the libs directory that don't have matching signed framework RSLs?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Taking the specific example of SDK 4.5.0.20967, the SDK includes the following signed framework RSLs (`.swz` files) in `"<sdk_path>\frameworks\rsls"`:

```
  advancedgrids_4.5.0.20967.swz
  charts_4.5.0.20967.swz
  framework_4.5.0.20967.swz
  mx_4.5.0.20967.swz --------> matching .swc is in libs\mx\mx.swc
  osmf_1.0.0.16316.swz
  rpc_4.5.0.20967.swz
  sparkskins_4.5.0.20967.swz
  spark_4.5.0.20967.swz
  spark_dmv_4.5.0.20967.swz
  textLayout_2.0.0.232.swz
```

The .swc files in the matching libs directory `"<sdk_path>\frameworks\libs"` are:

```
  advancedgrids.swc
  authoringsupport.swc ---> no .swz match
  charts.swc
  core.swc ---------------> no .swz match
  flash-integration.swc --> no .swz match
  framework.swc
  osmf.swc
  rpc.swc
  spark.swc
  sparkskins.swc
  spark_dmv.swc
  textLayout.swc
```

So 9 of 10 `.swz` files match the `..\libs\*.swc` exactly, with the one `.swz -> .swc` mismatch being `mx.swc` which is one subdir below.

What I'm mainly wondering about is the seemingly extra .swc files:

```
  authoringsupport.swc
  core.swc
  flash-integration.swc
```

What are they, and are they needed in a basic flex project?  Documentation on them is sparse/non-existent.

I expect that the question may be a bit misguided and the existence of those three `.swc` files in the root of the `frameworks\libs` directory is somewhat irrelevant.  However, the reason I was initially looking at this is that the IDE I'm experimenting with ([Amethyst](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Products/amethyst-ide/Amethyst-Product-Page)) seems to, at least, be including all `.swc` files it finds in the `frameworks\libs` directory into the project and I want to determine what I can manually remove.

Comment: Why do you want to remove any of them?  Having extra SWCs in the libray path should not affect final file size.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com - true.  I guess the answer to that is twofold: 1) I want to understand them, and 2) I'm making everything a locally sourced RSL (ie: adobe.com not being the primary, or even a failover, source) due to application deployment on an intranet behind a firewall.  RSLs that are not needed should not be in my deployment directory.

Answer (score 1):

These are default Adobe packages that enable things like bindings.

Best bet for figuring out what is required in your project because it's being implemented is to remove one at a time until your project fails to compile, and then restore them.